# how do I clone a git repository using node.js specific commands

Tags: node.js, git, git-clone

I'm wanting to clone a git repository using node.js command prompt. What are the commands I need to use to create a project area and then clone the repo to it?

Comment: Is this just a normal command prompt? `git clone <repo url>` doesn't work?

Comment: Do you mean using the [Nodejs REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)? Or do you mean you want to write a Nodejs *script* to do that? If you do mean the REPL, *why?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone github repo using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669037/how-to-clone-github-repo-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use `shelljs` or `nodegit` package.
Let me describe a way to use `shelljs`.

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
const path = process.cwd
shell.cd(path)
shell.exec('git clone https://github.com/<github-name>/<git-repos>')
```

Then it is a way to use `nodegit`.

```
const clone = require("nodegit").Clone.clone

const path = process.cwd

clone("https://github.com/<github-name>/<git-repos>", path)
  .then(function () {
    // Repo is available in `path`
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @Venus713's solution, you can use `node-cmd` to clone repositories.

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');
const clone = cmd.runSync('git clone https://github.com/<username>/<repo>');

// runSync returns the output of the command, which is console logged below.

console.log(clone);
```