# How to clone github repo using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, clone

I need a reliable way to clone a github repo and paste it into a local directory using node.js and any necessary npm packages.

This code is using the nodegit library and doesn't work to clone a github repo. it creates a single folder named .git and copies none of the files from the repo. I have tried several libraries most of which have extremely complicated code or don't work. This was working before but now isn't. (it goes on and off as it pleases). pls help, I need a reliable code that clones a github repo from url and pastes it into a local directory. Thank you.

```
var nodegit = require('nodegit'),
    path = require('path');

var url = "https://github.com/atomicptr/dauntless-builder", //also tried https://github.com/atomicptr/dauntless-builder.git
    local = "C:/data",
    cloneOpts = {};

nodegit.Clone(url, local, cloneOpts).then(function (repo) {
    console.log("cloning succesful!");
    console.log("Cloned " + path.basename(url) + " to " + repo.workdir());
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

this code shows no errors, yet doesn't actually work to clone the repo.

Comment: if you do not care if user has `git` installed, you can resolve to using `child_process` and `exec` method to execute commands

Comment: have you tried using the [GitHub API's](https://developer.github.com/v3/)? or [nodegit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) for this.

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
const path = 'absolute/path/to/folder'
shell.cd(path)
shell.exec('git clone https://github.com/atomicptr/dauntless-builder')
```

Comment: Thank you :) would there also be a way to upload files from local machine to my github repo? if so can u please tell me? I am finding it quite hard to get any code working.

Comment: yes. you can do any commands in terminal in shelljs. for this example, you can add `shell.cd('dauntless-builder')` then, `shell.exec('git push')`

Comment: to work with GitHub you don't need to go through git, surely not CLI commands. also, git push won't work without authorization. you need to set the configuration using git config first.

Comment: @AZ_ you're against using CLI for accessing git repos??

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have git installed on the machine you could simply run the clone command from node.

```
const path = require('path');
const{ execSync } = require('child_process');

execSync('git clone repolink', {
  stdio: [0, 1, 2], // we need this so node will print the command output
  cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, ''), // path to where you want to save the file
})
```

Comment: Thank you :) would there also be a way to upload files from local machine to my github repo? if so can u please tell me? I am finding it quite hard to get any code working.

Comment: if you clone the repo with ssh instead of https and you set your ssh key corectly it shoul work with git push

Comment: This is the ideal solution as it doesn't require an npm package. It's also useful in that it uses execSync, which seems to be the only way to git clone from node without the process hanging, async exec f.ex never triggers the callback.

Comment: @ShukriAdams Do you have any links to that problem with async exec?

Answer (score 6):

Try the [git-clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-clone) npm package

```sh
npm i git-clone
```

```js
var clone = require('git-clone');

clone(repo, targetPath, [options], cb);
```

Supported options:

git: path to git binary; default: git (optional).

shallow: when true, clone with depth 1 (optional).

checkout: revision/branch/tag to check out (optional).

Comment: although it offers very limited options  . but its good to use